# How is http post method implemented?

Tags: php, http, post

I know want to know what happens behind the scene of a HTTP post method. 
i.e browser sends a HTTP post request to a server side script in PHP (eg).

How does PHP's $_POST variable get the values from the client.

Could someone explain in details or point to a guide.

Answer (score 4):

The HTTP protocol(*) specifies how the browser should send the request.

HTTP basically consists of a set of headers in plain text, separated by line feeds, followed by the data being transmitted. Inside the HTTP request, POST data is actually formatted pretty much the same as GET data; it's just in a different part of the HTTP headers.

You can use tools like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) to see exactly how the headers and data are formatted for incoming and outgoing HTTP requests. It's actually all quite simple to read, so you should be able to work it out just by looking.

Once it gets to the server, the PHP interpreter is responsible for translating the raw HTTP request data into its standard $_GET, $_POST, etc variables. This is something that PHP does for you.

Other languages (eg Perl) do not have this functionality built in, so a Perl programmer would have to have code in their program to parse the incoming request data into useful variables. Fortunately, even Perl has a standard library which can be included that does the job, so even Perl programmers don't generally have to write the code themselves any more.

The way PHP, and any other language, does it is simply string manipulation. As I said, the HTTP data is plain text and is received in simple string format, so it's just a case of breaking it down by splitting it on question mark and equal sign characters.

As PHP does it all behind the scenes, you probably don't need to worry about the exact mechanisms it uses, but the PHP source code is available if you really want to find out.

I said it's all in plain text. HTTPS, of course, is encrypted. However by the time PHP gets hold of it, the Apache server has already done the decryption, so as far as PHP is concerned it's still plain text.

*(*) Before anyone pulls me up on it, yes, I know that saying "HTTP protocol" is a redundancy, like "ATM machine" or "PIN number".*

Comment: As for redundancies, what about "$_GET, $_POST variables"?  Last i checked, any word starting with a $ is a variable by definition....  :)  (Hey, you asked for it.)

Comment: @cHao - hehe. yep, I guess I did. :)

Answer (score 1):

The browser encodes the data according to the [content-type of the form](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#form-content-type), then transmits it as the body of a [POST](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) request. PHP then picks it up and populates `$_POST` with the names and values (performing special handling when the name includes the characters `[` and `]` or `.`).

Comment: It turns `.` into `_` (for historical reasons, mostly; used to be that every variable in the form got turned into a real variable.  Google for "register_globals" for details on that last part).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to get a capturing proxy (e.g. [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/)) or a network capture tool (e.g. [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)) and watch your own browsing traffic for a while; it will give you a nice view of the issue.

Other than that, POST is rather similar to GET, except that the data is sent in the body of the request instead of the URL, and there are two ways to encode them (multipart-form-data in addition to the urlencode that's shared with GET)

Comment: There are few ways that work with *forms* in a browser, but XHR POSTs can (and usually do) use JSON, XML, etc rather than either url-encoding or multipart/form-data.  Course, then you generally have to read the POST data and decode it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's ilustrate step by step, starting with a page containing a [form action="foo.php" method="post"]

Once you click submit (or hit enter), browser will trigger an event named "submit". This event can be catched internally for processing with javascript/dom, and this is what most sites do for validation or Ajax routines.

If routines does not stop the flow with a return false, browser continues to process the post request (this process is the same as making a post with XMLHttpRequest Object).

Browser will check first method, action and content encoding, then parse inputs values to know the size of data it will send, and encode it.

Finally it send something like this (raw values):

```
POST /foo.php HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 7

foo=bar
```

This is a POST request. But note that it can send content-length and send variables in chunks. Browser and server know this can happen (this is the POST method purpose). When a server receives a POST request, it keeps listening to the browser until the content received match the informed content length.

Now the other side. Server receives the request, listen the content, parse it (foo = bar; xxx = baz), and make it available on its environment for that specific request, thus you can catch it with PHP or Python, or Java...

That's it. Ah note you can pass both GET and POST variables in the same request!

Using a [form action="foo.php?someVar=123&anotherVar=TRUE" method="post"]

Will make the browser send the request as

```
POST /foo.php?someVar=123&anotherVar=TRUE HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 7

foo=bar
```

And server when parsing this request will make the following variables available:

- GET[someVar] = 123
- GET[anotherVar] = TRUE
- POST[foo] = bar